# Why don't WP themes download completely on my localhost (XAMMP)?

Tags: localhost, xampp

When I active a WP theme, it does not completely download.  The theme is not reproduced exactly (no graphics, no background, etc.). I was expecting a WYSIWYG. The widgets,etc. appear as random sentences. I localhosting using XAMMP.

Comment: Your question not clear, as you say after theme activate it does not download. Okay I think do you mean after theme install. From where you download theme from themes page? Or with FTP.

Comment: Add code `define('WP_DEBUG', true ); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );` in `wp-config.php` to file it will show you the error on display and also generate log file in `/wp-content/debug.log` hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

After Installing you need to import DEMO content provided by theme developer if not then try connecting with Theme Developers. Whenever you install a theme from WordPress.org store they will provide only the theme :), check if there is an option for demo content.